# How to know the Kubernetes API all process when use kubectl for crd resources

Tags: kubernetes

I want to know that how to use api to curd my crd resources with api. And I can write a sdk to control resources.

Use kubectl just

```sh
kubectl get inferenceservices test-sklearn -n kserve-test

kubectl apply -f xx.yaml -n kserve-test
kubectl delete -f xx.yaml -n kserve-test
```

```yaml
apiVersion: "serving.kubeflow.org/v1beta1"
kind: "InferenceService"
metadata:
  name: "test-sklearn"
spec:
  predictor:
    sklearn:
        storageUri: "http://xxxx"
```

Answer (score 1):

get call process in `process_log`

```
kubectl get inferenceservices test-sklearn -n kserve-test --v=8  > process_log 2>&1
```

use kubectl proxy to test

```
kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts=^.*
```

TEST to get resource status

```
GET http://xxx:8001/apis/serving.kubeflow.org/v1beta1/namespaces/kserve-test/inferenceservices/test-sklearn
```